# How change default white background WebView Flex

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flexbuilder

My problem is, that my app has black background. I inserted webview for showing HTML page, but when page is loading, background of webview is white. I need to have black background because app and page has black background. Is it possible? I found answers only for Android, but no for Flash Builder Mobile.

I tried set this in additional compiler arguments -default-background-color #000000 , but nothing happened.

Thank for advices

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="example"
        creationComplete="webexample(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            protected var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();

            protected var counter:int = 0;
            protected var url:String = "http://www.blackpages.at/";

            protected function addedToStageHandler():void
            {
            }

            protected function removedFromStageHandler():void
            {
                webView.dispose();
                stage.removeEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, orientationChangeHandler);
            }

            protected function orientationChangeHandler(event:StageOrientationEvent):void
            {
                resizeWebView();
            }

            protected function resizeWebView():void
            {
                webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            }

            public function webexample(event:FlexEvent):void
            {

                webView.stage = stage;
                resizeWebView();
                webView.loadURL(url);
                stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, orientationChangeHandler);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                    webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                }   
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable hardware acceleration:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Instead of `webview` use reference to your `WebView`.
Had the same issue and fixed it this way.

Comment: Could you explain how to disable hardware acceleration? I tried to find some tutorial, but nothing found.

Comment: Look at the code snippet. Where is wvBrowser use reference to your WebView object.

Comment: I tried, but it gives me error - Call to a possibly undefined method setLayerType through a reference with static type StageWebView.

Comment: You need to use this code only on devices where API Level is >= 11